# OpenOCD doesn't open a gdb connection for a ST nucleo-h743zi board

Tags: stm32, openocd, nucleo

I have successfully flashed a nucleo-h743zi board with a small app that blinks an LED and sends strings through the UART.

I'm now trying to connect to it with gdb, using OpenOCD v 0.12.0.

After building it, I execute this:

```
$./build/bin/openocd -f tcl/interface/stlink.cfg -c "transport select hla_swd" -f tcl/target/stm32h7x.cfg
```

And I obtain this:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-rc2+dev-00989-g9501b263e (2022-12-15-15:37)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
hla_swd
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
```

(the command line returns after printing that)

I have tried as well

```
./build/bin/openocd -f ./build/share/openocd/scripts/board/st_nucleo_h743zi.cfg
```

and I obtain the same result.

I have double checked that the mentioned ports are not open with `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

As you can see, there is no `gdb` connection. I have tried `telnet localhost 4444` as well, and I obtain:

```
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that I had the STM32CubeProgrammer connected.

Comment: Delete the question as it makes no sense as you simply did a mistake. No value for the community

Comment: It might perfectly happen that others have the exact same problem and find the solution here.

Comment: they can also do not connect the cable or forget power the board or look at the wrong computer screen. Are those issues worth answers here?